# Backup SQL Database using C++ sql.h

Tags: c++, mysql, sql, sql-server

I an trying to create a backup.bak file using C++. When I use this command

`BACKUP DATABASE myDB TO DISK = 'D:\folder\MyDatabase.bak'`

in Microsoft SQL Server Management it works perfectly fine

but when i exectute the same command in c++ using

```
SQLExecDirect(SQLStatementHandle, (SQLCHAR*)SQLQuery2, SQL_NTS)
```

i get error number 42000  which means --    Syntax error or access violation    *StatementText contained an SQL statement that was not preparable or contained a syntax error.

The user did not have permission to execute the SQL statement contained in *StatementText.

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqlexecdirect-function?view=sql-server-2017

although the command is same

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: Display or log or trace the contents of SQLQuery2 somewhere to double-check ... your code most probably damages it somehow.

Answer (score 2):

> The user did not have permission to execute the SQL statement
>   contained in...

This is because backup operations require extra permissions that can be granted:

On a server level:

```
GRANT BACKUP DATABASE TO [loginInUse]
```

Alternatively, on some certain database level:

```
use db
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_backupoperator', 'loginInUse'
```